# will Lightning web Component make a way for Lightning in IE?

Tags: browser, lightning-web-components

Lightning web component provides better support for ES6 and ES7, not available in Aura. We can do more in less code. It also transpiles code to work with IE 11 and other browsers that are missing some features.

Does it mean we can expect from salesforce to extend their support for Lightning in IE? Have anyone any idea about the future roadmap?

Comment: I got this:- For earlier versions of these browsers, and for IE 11, Lightning Web Components uses compatibility mode. Compatibility mode uses the lowest common denominator—code is transpiled down to ES5 and the required polyfills are added. Lightning web components work in compatibility mode, but performance suffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, IE 11 support is only provided so far as to comply with [IE 11 Extended Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233325&language=en_US&type=1), set to expire in December 2020. Note that KB 000233325 (linked above) states that IE 11 has inherent security problems, such as not supporting CSP. This means that simply using IE 11 is a security risk. Eventually, in order to provide an optimal experience to all users, IE 11 support eventually needs to be removed anyways. IE 11 has no support for Shadow DOM, so a polyfill is used (and is the reason why LWC currently doesn't use native Shadow DOM).